# ng include not working in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome

I am new to AngularJs. I am trying to use ng-include directive in my index.html file to include header template. IN my local I am running it in standalone mode and not on any web server. The index page is loading the header file perfectly on firefox wheras on Chrome. I get an error stating "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."

Some more logs from the error stack is pasted below:

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "file:///Users/pradeep/Angular_demo/header.html". index.html:305
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
file:///Users/pradeep/Angular_demo/header.html.

Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. angular.js:8109
(anonymous function) angular.js:8109
sendReq

Please help me resolving this issue on Chrome so that I can run this as standalone application.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a path that is relative to the app directory. ex: `header.html` if `Angular_demo` is the project's root directory.

dont try to access resources through the `file` protocol

Comment: I am not using relative path to access. to make it simple, the included html is in the same directory as the index.html. below is the code snippet from index.html    <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>

Comment: http://erichonorez.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/a-basic-web-server-with-node-js-and-express/

Comment: follow the instructions in that link to quickly set up a simple static web server and serve the site from it. then you access the site in the browser @ `http://localhost:3000`. the browser is going to choke on attempts to make "cross-domain" resource requests.  the domain of your machine is `localhost`.

Comment: navigate to the `Angular_demo` directory in your console (`cd && cd Angular_demo`, the first `cd` is to make sure you are at the home directory of your machine...), then execute `npm install express` (assumes you have node.js installed already). then create the server file in the root directory (`Angular_demo`). then execute the file by running `node server.js`.  this starts the server and begins it listening on port 3000. this line: `express.static(__dirname)` in `server.js` serves up all files within `cd`, which is `Angular_demo`. now go to browser and navigate to `localhost:3000`

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborated steps to set up Nodejs. Now its working.