# ng-include and ng-route are not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

The below ng-include and ng-route are working fine in FireFox. But, when i see in google chrome it is not showing any thing. it is just showing blank white page.

please suggest me solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sampleApp">

    <div ng-include="'top-navi.html'"></div>

    <div ng-view></div>


</body>

<script>

var module = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

module.config(['$routeProvider', 
function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/route1/:param',{
templateUrl: 'route1.html',
controller: 'RouteController'
})
.when('/route2/:param',{
templateUrl: 'route2.html',
controller: 'RouteController'
})
.otherwise({
rediretTo: '/'
});
} 
]);
module.controller("RouteController", function($scope, $routeParams){
$scope.param = $routeParams.param;
})
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng include not working in chrome browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565322/ng-include-not-working-in-chrome-browser)

Comment: Does the console show any error?

Comment: yes. there is an error.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/personal/samples/angularJs/websites/sample-03/top-navi.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:7918

Answer (score 0):

You need to install web server to your local environment.

I.E.: Install npm package called `lite-server` to run your code.

[npm lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server)

Comment: as it is a just html pages, if i transfer these files to the client, client can not see it. what might be solution for this.

Comment: You mean client run the html file by double clicking on it?

Comment: I installed lite-server also. still it is not working

Comment: yes. if the client wants to run as just html files. if i am running from localhost (as server files) it is working fine.